# Check(validate) radio buttons with an if else if true no alert if not checked alert must be check

Tags: javascript, forms, radio-button, checked

This is what I have on the HTML side of things. I have a form with the id of products, a name of myForm, an action tag a method of get, and onsubmit returns the function validateForm(); I have a full fledged order form

```
 <form id="products"name="myForm"action="FormProcessor.html"method="get"
onsubmit="return validateForm();">

    <label for="payment">Payment Method?</label>
    <input  id="visa" name="credit_card" type="radio" value="Visa"  />
    <label for="visa">Visa</label>
    <input  id="masterCard" name="credit_card" type="radio"value="MasterCard" />
    <label for="mastercard">MasterCard</label>
    <input  id="ae"name="credit_card"type="radio"value="American Express" />
    <label for="americanexpress">American Express</label><br>
```

This is what I have on the js side of things, I am also trying to write it in vanilla js. I have not learned jQuery yet i am still new to programming. I am not sure why it is not alerting.

```
function validateForm() {
       var p_form = document.getElementById("products");
       p_form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
       var payment_array = document.getElementsByName("credit_card");

          for(var i = 0; i < payment_array.length; i++) {
              if(payment_array[i].checked) {
                 selection_made = true;
                 break;
               }
           }

               if(!selection_made) {
                  event.preventDefault();
                  alert("Payment Method must be selected.");
                  return false;
                }
         });}
```

Answer (score 0):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/e4gfs67o/1/

Solution:

HTML:

```
<form id="products" name="myForm" action="FormProcessor.html" method="get">
    <label for="payment">Payment Method?</label>
    <input  id="visa" name="credit_card" type="radio" value="Visa"  />
    <label for="visa">Visa</label>
    <input  id="masterCard" name="credit_card" type="radio" value="MasterCard" />
    <label for="mastercard">MasterCard</label>
    <input  id="ae"name="credit_card" type="radio" value="American Express" />
    <label for="americanexpress">American Express</label><br>
    <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
var form = document.getElementById('products');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    var radios = document.getElementsByName('credit_card'),
        len = radios.length,
        i = 0,
        selected = false;

    for (; i < len; i++) {
        if (radios[i].checked) {
            selected = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (selected) {
        return true;   
    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('Payment Method must be selected.');
        return false;
    }
});
```